# Receiving push notification even after the app is deleted iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I implemented push notification in my app.

It is working fine.

Now the problem is even after  i deleted  my app from device it is getting the push notifications.

So is there any way to unregister the app from push notification when it is deleted from the device.

Hoping for your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ads by any chance?  if so, serves you right.

Comment: User will be able to fix it by himself in settings of device. Not a solution, but an option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Apple push notification there is something called - Feedback Service. So when a user deletes an app, the service provider should ideally stop sending notifications to that device. But Apple does not notify the service that "this device is not using your app, dont send notifications". So instead you need to poll for this info.

Every day you might need to hit Apple Notification servers asking it to give you device Ids who have deleted your app. Once you get them you mark them in your DB as deleted thereby not sending any more notifications. Hope this is what you wanted.

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/BinaryProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH13-SW12) -

> ... Apple Push Notification Service includes a feedback
>   service that APNs continually updates with a per-application list of
>   devices for which there were failed-delivery attempts. The devices are
>   identified by device tokens encoded in binary format. Providers should
>   periodically query the feedback service to get the list of device
>   tokens for their applications, each of which is identified by its
>   topic. Then, after verifying that the application hasn’t recently been
>   re-registered on the identified devices, a provider should stop
>   sending notifications to these devices.
>
> Access to the feedback service takes place through a binary interface
>   similar to that used for sending push notifications. You access the
>   production feedback service via feedback.push.apple.com, port 2196;
>   you access the sandbox feedback service via
>   feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com, port 2196. As with the binary
>   interface for push notifications, you must use TLS (or SSL) to
>   establish a secured communications channel. The SSL certificate
>   required for these connections is the same one that is provisioned for
>   sending notifications. To establish a trusted provider identity, you
>   should present this certificate to APNs at connection time using
>   peer-to-peer authentication.

Be sure to checkout - [Issues with Feedback Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG34)

Comment: so how to know who all deleted the app,or is there any delegate method to be called when an app is deleting form a device.Kindly help please..

Comment: check updated answer, also this part of your push framework does not involve much change in the app. Its all backend changes.

Answer (score 0):

Having not seen this answer so far, there is a small note in the Apple "Troubleshooting Push Notifications" document.
In short, if you delete the last push enabled app, the persistent connection from the device to Apples push server is broken before the server is told that the app has been deleted.
Solution: keep at least one push enabled app on your device.

There is the explanation from the document:

> Issues with Using the Feedback Service
>   If you remove your app from your device or computer and then send a push notification to it, you would expect to have the device token rejected, and the invalidated device token should appear on the feedback service. However, if this was the last push-enabled app on the device or computer, it will not show up in the feedback service. This is because deleting the last app tears down the persistent connection to the push service before the notice of the deletion can be sent.
>
> You can work around this by leaving at least one push-enabled app on the device or computer in order to keep the persistent connection up. To keep the persistent connection to the production environment up, just install any free push-enabled app from the App Store and you should then be able to delete your app and see it appear in the feedback service.

Recall that each push environment has its own persistent connection. So to keep the persistent connection to the sandbox environment up, install another development push-enabled app."