# Unregister push notification when user deletes the app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am stucked in starnge kind of situation that In my app I have push notifications. When user deletes the a app and reinstall some how push notification resumes and start receiving to user before he gets register.

I have all code of push notification after registration. Is there any way to unregister push notification when user deletes the app.

Even user don't open the app and he start getting the push notifications.

Comment: If a user doesn't have the app installed on the device, he/she won't get push notifications. My guess is that server-side you will receive feedback from APNS with the bad tokens, which you would likely want to handle/clean-up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Receiving push notification even after the app is deleted iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535548/receiving-push-notification-even-after-the-app-is-deleted-iphone)