# App Deleting Behavior for Push Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I implemented push notification in my app. It is working fine. My question is that 
1) After deleting the app, how Apple server know to stop sending the Push to device. Is there any service to notify the Apple server. 
2) If device has no network connectivity then how Apple server will be notify about deletion of app from device.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535548/receiving-push-notification-even-after-the-app-is-deleted-iphone) might help you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> The Apple Push Notification service includes a feedback service to
> give you information about failed remote notifications. When a remote
> notification cannot be delivered because the intended app does not
> exist on the device, the feedback service adds that device’s token to
> its list.
>
> [...]
>
> As a provider, you are responsible for the following aspects of remote
> notifications:
>
> [...] Connect regularly with the feedback service and fetch the
> current list of those devices that have repeatedly reported
> failed-delivery attempts. Then stop sending notifications to the
> devices associated with those apps. See The Feedback Service for more
> information.

So, a third-party provider (Parse, Urban Airship etc.) is responsible for connecting regularly with the Apple feedback service and fetch the current list of devices that have repeatedly reported failed-delivery attempts. Pushes will once again be sent to a device if the given device token has been re-registered (timestamp has been updated since the feedback entry was generated).

So to my understanding, the feedback service doesn’t distinguish between the two separate cases you mention (lost connection and app removal). In both of these cases a given device’s token will be added to the feedback service’s token list, which again signals that pushes should not be sent.

Sources:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3